# Cutting tool for hollow tubes

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, cutting, tools

We have steel hollow tubes of 80 mm length and 0.5 mm cross section, that we need to cut in smaller pieces of 10.1 and 10.5 mm length. We have been using utility knifes with very poor results.

I am looking for a tool that can do the job. Something like scissors or pliers, to be handled manually.

Every answer or suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: How big is the hollow? What material are they made of?

Comment: Is 0.5mm your external diameter or your wall thickness? And what is the value for whichever of those dimensions it isn't?

Comment: please edit the question with required info. Diameter, thickness, required precision of the cut, quantity of cuts needed..

Comment: What are "very poor results"? Is the issue with the user, the tool, or the method?

Comment: I would use an abrasive cutoff disc mounted in a table saw with a holding jig made for the job that rides in a mitre slot. Feed slowly so the the disc nibbles away at the tubing without grabbing it. The accuracy of your cuts will depend on the quality of your holding jig.

Comment: Forgot to mention that your holding jig should incorporate a dowel rod that supports the inside of the tube right up to the point where the tube is cut.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thanks for the comments and questions. The details: Is a stainless steel hollow tube (cannula). Inner diameter: 0.1 mm - Outer diameter: 0.2 mm - Length 80 mm.

Comment: @MCL  The only way to cut tubing that fine without destroying it is with a laser, do you have one ?  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a skilled metalworker will come along and lough at me for this, but I don't think you can cut to 0.1 mm accuracy with many hand tools. I see these ways:

- using a small saw (your tubes are fairly small) and then file down to the desired length.
- I think pliers or bolt cutters could cut through your tube, but will likely chinch it shut
- Or get a tube cutting device - rollers opposite a blade, with a thread to push the blade into the tube. [Look here for these look like](https://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Plumbing-Tools-Pipe-Tube-Cutting/N-5yc1vZc4ft). Maybe you can get sub-mm accuracy with these.
- Whatever tool you use, if at all possible use internal support (since your dimensions indicate a very small tube this may be hard to implement), a wood dowel or plug could work (hattip to @fred_dot_u)

Comment: They sound better than my suggestions, but the op did ask for suggestions so we should be fine...

Comment: A hacksaw with internal support such as wooden dowel should work well, combined with filing for final precision. Tube cutting devices are good too, especially with internal support.

Comment: Thanks! We are using a small saw. The problem with that method is that sometimes the tube bends. I will try to find a tool like the ones that are suggested and build a plastic dowel.

Answer (score 0):

Can you flatten them and use a hole punch, at least there are leather punches used for punching holes in leather...

Or put a mandrel inside and use the punch...

Comment: For now I am using a small saw but the problem is that sometimes bends the cannula instead of cutting it.